# ItemPoinnts SUM

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

That is my script for calculating ItemPoints on Slots 0-12

```
SELECT TOP 25 _Char.CharName16 , 
              _Char.CurLevel , 
              SUM(_Items.OptLevel) AS ItemPoints FROM
             _Char 
             INNER JOIN
             _Inventory ON _Char.CharID = _Inventory.CharID 
             INNER JOIN
             _Items ON _Inventory.ItemID = _Items.ID64
where _char.charname16 not like 'GM'         AND 
      _char.Charname16 not like '%xprodigy%' AND 
     _char.charname16 not like '%-%'         AND 
     _inventory.Slot between 0 and 12 
GROUP BY _Char.CharName16,_Char.CurLevel 
Order by _Char.CurLevel desc ,SUM(_items.Optlevel) desc");
```

One account I don't have items on me is Naked and this is result

[image]

Normal is ItemPoints : 0 and the other problems is put one item +5 normal on me and the ItemPoints :

```
125  ( 130 -5 =125 normal 130 +5=135)
```

Anyone can helping me to fix that?

Comment: I recommend taking some time to properly format your query so it's readable.

Comment: I waited for almost 3 hours
I think it's best if DB is 0 not to read the script.